# Passing DTS variable inside python script in ssis

Tags: python, ssis, ssis-2008

I am trying to using a python script using the "Execute Task" tool in ssis.However, i am not sure if i will be able to use one of the runtime variable inside the python script. Eg:

```
#inputval.py

inputval = dts.value("test").toString()
print(inputval)
```

Is there any chance ? . Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reference the value but not in that manner.

Python won't have access to the Variables collection so you'll have to use a different method for communication. The [Execute Package Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141166.aspx) supports either a Variable for Standard Input or for Arguments. Either one should work

Within your python script, you'll need to work with the `sys.argv` collection (code approximate based on 2.7 recollections with 3.0 print flair)

```
for inputval in sys.argv:
    print (inputval)
```

or skipping the first element, we'd have something like

```
# we can skip the first element since that is name of script
for inputval in sys.argv[1:]
    print (inputval)
```